# How to customize child view from parent view?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create customizable view like below.

```
<ParentView>
    <ParentView.Child>
        <ChildView Text="Hello, Parent!"/>
    </ParentView.Child>
</ParentView>
```

#### ParentView

ParentView.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <CustomizeView:ChildView
        x:Name="NestedView" />
</ContentView.Content>
```

ParentView.xaml.cs

```
public static BindableProperty ChildProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: nameof(Child),
    returnType: typeof(ChildView),
    declaringType: typeof(ParentView),
    defaultValue: null,
    propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
    {
         (b as ParentView).Child = (ChildView)n;
    }
);
public ChildView Child
{
    get => (ChildView)GetValue(ChildProperty);
    set => SetValue(ChildProperty, value);
}
```

#### ChildView

ChildView.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Label x:Name="Label" Text="Hello, Child!" />
</ContentView.Content>
```

ChildView.xaml.cs

```
public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: nameof(Text),
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(ChildView),
    defaultValue: string.Empty,
    propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
    {
        (b as ChildView).Label.Text = (string)n;
    }
);

public string Text
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}
```

What I expect is **Hello, Parent!**.
However I got **Hello, Child!**.

[image]

How can I create customizable `View` inside like `ContentView`?

Here is [Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/64386200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **ParentView.xaml.cs** , you invoked the line

```
(b as ParentView).Child= (ChildView)n;
```

You only change the value of **Child** , not the Content of the ParentView

So the fastest way is to modify it like following

```
(b as ParentView).Content= (ChildView)n;
```

### Update

In your case , it seems that you misunderstand the logic in your project .

When you define the following code in ContentPage

```
<Frame
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <CustomizeView:ParentView>
            <CustomizeView:ParentView.Child>
                <CustomizeView:ChildView
                    Text="Hello, Parent!"/>
            </CustomizeView:ParentView.Child>
        </CustomizeView:ParentView>
    </Frame>
```

Even if you set the **Text** as `Hello, Parent!` , the value will not been changed because we could not set the **NestedView** as a new ChildView (we can only change its property) .

like

```
propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
{
   var childview = (b as ParentView).NestedView as ChildView;
   childview.Text = (n as ChildView).Text;
});
```

Comment: Nice, but how if he want only to change the child property without affecting the whole "Content"? What is missing in his code some property changed to be raised?

Comment: Nice it's better now. In one line? `var childview = (b as ParentView).NestedView.Text = (n as ChildView).Text;`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT so instead replace **NestedView** to new **ChildView** (`(b as ParentView).NestedView = n as ChildView`), replace value of **NestedView** from **ChildView** value (`(b as ParentView).NestedView.Text = (n as ChildView).Text`). Am I getting it right?